# Execute different function based on random() on Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, random, server

My website calls a js file (named *file.js*) like this:

```
<script src="urltothefile/file.js"></script>
```

The `.js` file itself starts with a `random()` function
where if the number is lower than 50 it should print "nothing here to see"
and if it's higher it should execute a javascript code.

Can that be done?!

Comment: use the `onload` event  on the body with the function, shoudn't be a problem

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Lower than 50 out of what?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.random() * 100` return a number between 0 to 100.

```js
if (Math.random() * 100 > 50) {
  alert('nothing here to see');
}
else {
  // Do the code..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a function out of that. Something like...

```
function prob(value){
  if(value < 0 || value > 1) throw "Value should be between 0 and 1.";
  return Math.random() < value;
}

if(prob(.5)) {
  //do something
  //note: i prefer this inverted logic
}
else {
  alert('nothing here to see');
}
```

Comment: Oh wow that looks nicely done! But i have a question. Is it anyway possible to "hide" that js file? Because if someone views my site's source,he can just copy paste all of that. Can it be done without visitors seeing your part of code?!
p.s: I don't care if they see my function,i want that the functions you use mustn't be seen

Comment: You can't hide javascript. You can minify it so it will be harder to copy/paste it.

Comment: Minify and _obfuscate_ in case you need to go research those processes or search for tools that do it for you.